# Apple iOS App Reject: Alamofire IPv6 not Supported

Tags: alamofire, ipv6, appstore-approval

Recently we submitted the new version of the app for review, it hasbeen rejected

> Your app crashes on iPad and iPhone running iOS 9.3.5 connected to an IPv6 network

But i only used the Alamofire 3.4.1 for API Requests, with a domain name (not IP Address), and it is IPv6 Compatible
Here is the results of the ipv6-test.com

[image: IPv6 Result of mydomain.com]

Our ISPs not Providing IPv6 Only network, to check our app, We followed [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1) procedure to setup the IPv6 in Mac, then it works here, after we submitted the build again, but it again rejected for the same reason

Can anybody suggest, how can we troubleshoot the issue/ is any thing wrong in my current environment

Comment: it is no need to have a ipv6 server.

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem, have you managed to make it work ?

Comment: yes, this is not the issue of IPv6 or Alamofire, it is working fine - Our app crashes in IPAD for the UIAlertController Popover Source Rect not set, after that we resubmitted the app and it is approved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found that the issue is not regarding IPv6 or Alamofire, it is working fine - My app crashes in IPAD for the UIAlertController Popover Source Rect not set, after that we resubmitted the app and it is approved
These may help someone
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/176301#176301
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/176303#176303

Answer (score 1):

Try delete AAAA record of your domain.
So that your app can use NAT64 network to access your server other use ipv6 directly.

And it may help debug the issue.